# Puzzle regarding big-oh, something between logarithm and polynomial

Tags: algorithm, big-o

We know that log(n) is O(n^0.000001) and even (log(n))^9999 = O(n^0.000001).

I want to find a function f(n) such that (log(n))^k = O(f(n)) for every k AND f(n) = O(n^e) for every e > 0. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your notations, let's consider
 `k` and `e`, and note `g(n) = log(n)^k` and `h(n) = n^e`.

Given real numbers `a > 1` and `1 > b > 0`, consider

```
f(n) = a^((log(n))^b)
```

We have

```
log(g(n)/f(n)) = k.log(log(n)) - log(a).(log(n))^b
               ---> -Inf as n ---> +Inf because log(a) > 0 and b > 0

=> g(n)/f(n) ---> 0 as n ---> +Inf
=> g(n) = o(f(n))
=> g(n) = O(f(n))
```

And

```
log(f(n)/h(n)) = log(a).(log(n))^b - e.log(n)
               ----> -Inf as n ---> +Inf because b < 1

=> f(n)/h(n) ---> 0 as n --> +Inf
=> f(n) = o(h(n))
=> f(n) = O(h(n))
```

#